# How to open files copied to android file system using Adobe pdf reader

Tags: file-system, adobe-reader

I have copied two dozen pdf's to the `DCIM` on the Android. How do I access them?

The Adobe Reader offers the following options:

- M**y Documents** - which points to a directory underneath the Adobe Reader and does not offer any way to configure (no `File Open` dialog)
- **Local** - which only has one file "Getting Started.pdf"
- **Document Cloud**
- **DropBox**

So .. where is the standard `File Open` dialog to allow navigation to the  directory containing the copied pdf's?   This is an `6.0.1` Android device.

**Update**  I *also* copied the files to the `Android/data/com.adobe.reader/files/Downloads` directory (where the "Getting Started.pdf" lives).  They ***still*** do not show up.

Comment: DCIM? That's for camera images, not documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files that I copied over *did* ***eventually*** show up: after several minutes.  The files are showing up now in both the `DCIM`, `Downloads` and the `Android/data/com.adobe.reader/files/Downloads` directories.

It is not clear why the delay .. Simply closing and re-opening the Acrobat Reader did *not* solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Comments added to PDF files using Adobe Reader on Android are lost forever. So start crying NOW and then you can start picking up your life again sooner.

By lost I mean they are stuck on the device and cannot be moved off the device by any means known to man.

I realize this doesn't answer the OP's question. But my travails led me here.

BTW, Foxit on Android seems to somehow be able to access the comments from the hidden Reader file. I had another copy of the file on the SD Card containing the uncommented file. Opening this file in Reader caused it to save the file in the hidden location. But opening the uncommented file in Foxit seems to have somehow extracted the Reader comments from the hidden file. This seems pretty unlikely, so I suggest testing.

Comment: This is a reasonable _new_ / _separate_ question: if you format it as such I can upvote. It is not an answer to this question so is - as you noted- not perfectly situated _here_. good luck!